# Why can't I find the WATCH window?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm really new to both Python and VS Code.  I'm seeing in the documentation that VS Code has a WATCH window - but I don't really see the definitive path to finding it.  Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in the debugging side bar (left-hand column by default), usually the second section from the top, when the debugger is running (see the [debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)).

Comment: I saw that documentation, but I still don't see the WATCH window.  Is there a configuration setting or something?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's collapsible and you can drag it around. You can try using the `Run: Focus on Watch view` command which will make it visible and select it to help you find it.